# Camera2 APIでプレビュー画像がゆがむ

Tags: java, android, api, kotlin, camera

teratailでも質問していますがこちらでも質問させていただきます。https://teratail.com/questions/232090

### 問題

Camera2 APIを使用してカメラを使用したいです。
とりあえずカメラのプレビューをTextureViewに表示させることはできたのですが、プレビューが歪んで表示されてしまいます。

具体的にいますと、縦画面時は上下に伸びたような形となり、横画面時は横に伸びたように表示されます。

これをどうにかして正常に表示できるようにしたいです。

### 試したこと

端末が対応している撮影サイズを取得して最大サイズをプレビューサイズとすることでうまくいくとの情報がありましたので、撮影サイズのリストを取得し、その最大サイズ（配列の要素0個目）をsetDefaultBufferSizeしてみましたがうまくいきませんでした。

お知恵をお貸しください。

### コード

DriveRecorderActivity.kt

```
package caios.android.drive_recorder

import android.content.Context
import android.content.Intent
import android.content.pm.PackageManager
import android.graphics.*
import android.hardware.camera2.CameraCaptureSession
import android.hardware.camera2.CameraCharacteristics
import android.hardware.camera2.CameraDevice
import android.hardware.camera2.CameraManager
import android.net.Uri
import android.os.Build
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity
import android.os.Bundle
import android.provider.Settings
import android.util.Log
import android.util.Size
import android.view.Surface
import android.view.TextureView
import android.view.WindowManager
import androidx.core.app.ActivityCompat
import androidx.core.content.ContextCompat
import kotlinx.android.synthetic.main.activity_drive_recorder.*
import java.lang.Exception
import java.util.jar.Manifest

class DriveRecorderActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    private lateinit var textureView: TextureView

    private var permissionRequestCount = 0
    private var cameraDevice: CameraDevice? = null
    private var cameraSize = Size(1920, 1080)
    private var cameraCaptureSession: CameraCaptureSession? = null

    private val cameraManager: CameraManager by lazy {
        getSystemService(Context.CAMERA_SERVICE) as CameraManager
    }
    private val cameraId: String by lazy {
        cameraManager.cameraIdList[0]
    }

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_drive_recorder)

        textureView = ADR_TextureView
        configurationTransform()
    }

    override fun onResume() {
        super.onResume()

        if (textureView.isAvailable) {
            checkPermissionAndOpenCamera()
        }
        else {
            textureView.surfaceTextureListener = object : TextureView.SurfaceTextureListener {
                override fun onSurfaceTextureAvailable(p0: SurfaceTexture?, p1: Int, p2: Int) {
                    checkPermissionAndOpenCamera()
                }

                override fun onSurfaceTextureDestroyed(p0: SurfaceTexture?): Boolean {
                    return true
                }

                override fun onSurfaceTextureUpdated(p0: SurfaceTexture?) {

                }

                override fun onSurfaceTextureSizeChanged(p0: SurfaceTexture?, p1: Int, p2: Int) {
                    configurationTransform()
                }
            }
        }
    }

    override fun onPause() {
        super.onPause()
        closeCamera()
    }

    private fun openCamera() {
        if(ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, android.Manifest.permission.CAMERA) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) return

        setCameraSize()

        val cameraStateCallback = object : CameraDevice.StateCallback() {
            override fun onOpened(p0: CameraDevice) {
                cameraDevice = p0
                createCameraPreview()
            }

            override fun onDisconnected(p0: CameraDevice) {
                cameraDevice?.close()
                cameraDevice = null
            }

            override fun onError(p0: CameraDevice, p1: Int) {
                cameraDevice?.close()
                cameraDevice = null
            }
        }

        cameraManager.openCamera(cameraId, cameraStateCallback, handler)
    }

    private fun closeCamera() {
        cameraCaptureSession?.close()
        cameraDevice?.close()
    }

    private fun createCameraPreview(){
        try {
            val surfaceTexture = textureView.surfaceTexture
            surfaceTexture.setDefaultBufferSize(cameraSize.width, cameraSize.height)

            val surface = Surface(surfaceTexture)
            val previewRequestBuilder = cameraDevice!!.createCaptureRequest(CameraDevice.TEMPLATE_PREVIEW)
            previewRequestBuilder.addTarget(surface)

            val captureSessionStateCallback = object : CameraCaptureSession.StateCallback() {
                override fun onConfigured(p0: CameraCaptureSession) {
                    cameraCaptureSession = p0
                    cameraCaptureSession?.setRepeatingRequest(previewRequestBuilder.build(), null, null)
                }

                override fun onConfigureFailed(p0: CameraCaptureSession) {

                }
            }

            cameraDevice?.createCaptureSession(listOf(surface), captureSessionStateCallback, null)

            configurationTransform()
        }
        catch (e: Exception){
            Log.d(G_TAG, "$e")
        }
    }

    private fun setCameraSize() {
        val characteristic = cameraManager.getCameraCharacteristics(cameraId)
        val scm = characteristic.get(CameraCharacteristics.SCALER_STREAM_CONFIGURATION_MAP)
        val mCameraSize = scm?.getOutputSizes(SurfaceTexture::class.java) ?: return

        for(cameraSize in mCameraSize){
            Log.d(G_TAG, cameraSize.toString())
        }

        cameraSize = mCameraSize[0]

        configurationTransform()
    }

    private fun configurationTransform() {
        val matrix = Matrix()
        val centerX = textureView.width / 2f
        val centerY = textureView.height / 2f
        val orientation = getTextureViewOrientation() ?: return

        matrix.postRotate(-orientation.toFloat(), centerX, centerY)

        textureView.setTransform(matrix)
    }

    private fun getTextureViewOrientation(): Int?{
        try {
            return when (textureView.display.rotation) {
                Surface.ROTATION_0   -> 0
                Surface.ROTATION_90  -> 90
                Surface.ROTATION_180 -> 180
                Surface.ROTATION_270 -> 270
                else                 -> null
            }
        }
        catch (e: Exception){
            Log.d(G_TAG, "$e")
            return null
        }
    }

    private fun checkPermissionAndOpenCamera() {
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 23 && ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, android.Manifest.permission.CAMERA) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            if(ActivityCompat.shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale(this, android.Manifest.permission.CAMERA) || permissionRequestCount == 0) {
                ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this, arrayOf(android.Manifest.permission.CAMERA), 92)
                permissionRequestCount++
            }
            else {
                val intent = Intent(Settings.ACTION_APPLICATION_DETAILS_SETTINGS, Uri.fromParts("package", packageName, null))
                startActivity(intent)
            }
        }
        else {
            openCamera()
        }
    }

    override fun onRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode: Int, permissions: Array<out String>, grantResults: IntArray) {
        when(requestCode){
            92 -> {
                if(ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, android.Manifest.permission.CAMERA) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED){
                    openCamera()
                }
                else {
                    global.toast(this, "権限不足")
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

activity_drive_recorder.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/ADR_RootView"
    tools:context=".DriveRecorderActivity">

    <TextureView
        android:id="@+id/ADR_TextureView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

</FrameLayout>
```

Comment: この辺のどれかが参考になるかも。[How to change aspect ratio of camera2 preview?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/41221284/9014308), [Android Java: Camera2 preview image is stretched](https://stackoverflow.com/q/52530104/9014308), [Android Camera 2 preview size and devices aspect ratio](https://stackoverflow.com/q/37434494/9014308), [Camera display / preview in full screen does not maintain aspect ratio - image is skewed, stretched in order to fit on the screen](https://stackoverflow.com/q/16727836/9014308)

Answer (score 1):

コードを確認させていただきました。'0番目のサイズ(最大)'とご質問にありますが、ここに入る値はデバイスごとで変化し、かならずしも最大にはなりません。歪みをなくすためには同一の比率で表示して適切にトリムを行うなどの対処が必要になります。以下の二点の修正を試してみてください

- setCameraSizeで0番目でなく最大のプレビューサイズ(通常、デバイスのスクリーンサイズ)を取得するようにする
- configurationTransformでプレビューサイズのアスペクト比を計算して、得られた値でtextureViewをpostScaleやpreScaleする

記述がシンプルになりますのでCameraXなどの利用もご検討ください。以下のサイト様ではご希望の実装をされているかと思います。

https://dev.classmethod.jp/smartphone/android/android-camerax-preview/